# AppName doesn't change, after renaming in xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have two apps which are 90% same.So I have used the same code and renamed it in xcode.After that I have installed it in my device.So it is giving the previous appname not the new name.So Kindly tell me.Let me know if you need any more details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are refering to the label inside the app icon in the springboard (the iPhone "desktop") , you will need to open the YourApp-Info.plist (located, usually, in Supporting Files) and change the value for **Bundle display name** (or CFBundleDisplayName).

Answer (score 4):

go to your Xcode project, select the desired target, click on "Build settings" and look for "Product Name", now enter the new desired name.

Comment: Fixed it for me.  Selected answer above takes too long.

Answer (score 1):

To change the name of the app on the iOS home screen, you need to change the `CFBundleDisplayName` key in your app's Info.plist file.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009249-110725-TPXREF135

Comment: If you change the Bundle Display name your Product Name still remains the old one, changing the product name also modifies your bundle display name

Answer (score 1):

As everyone say, the `bundle display name` is the name displayed on your device.

You might want to change the `bundle identifier` too, but it's for corresponding to your provisionning profiles and to be posted on another identifier on the app store.

You might want to rename your Xcode project, I found yesterday a way to do this easily: click on your project name (on left panel), go on the right panel (open it if not) and change the "project name" textfield. it will ask you to rename lot of files automatically.

Finally, have you considered to create a new target, instead of creating a new project ? If the differences are just images and nib file, you can duplicate an app easily, this way.